# Mocked module function with Jest is never called

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a really weird situation where my Jest tests are passing in my Windows 10 desktop and Macbook Pro, but they are not passing in 2 of my other friends' Windows 10 desktops.

Code that is being tested

```
import { addTerminalItem } from '../../store'
...
class LoginUser extends EventHandler {
  ...
  async handle () {
    if (this.isFromOauthRedirect) {
      try {
        await this._handleOauthRedirect()
      } catch (e) {
        addTerminalItem(new ErrorMessage(e.message))
      }
      return
    }

    if (await zaClient.isUserLoggedIn('testUserId')) {
      // TODO: user is already logged in, do something
    } else {
      const loginStartSecret = uuidv4()
      localStorage.setItem(LOGIN_START_SECRET, loginStartSecret)
      addTerminalItem(new LoginMessage(loginStartSecret))
    }
  }
  ...
}

export const loginUser = new LoginUser()
```

---

The testing code does the following:

1. Adds invalid `LOGIN_START_SECRET` so that actual code throws exception entering the first `catch`.
2. Subscribes the event handler to the event `WELCOME_MESSAGE_RENDERED`.
3. Mocks the `store.addTerminalItem` module function.
4. Publishes the event so the above `async handle()` function is triggered.
5. Checks that the mocked function is called.

---

```
import * as store from '../../../store'
...
test('different login start secret in localstorage', async () => {
  localStorage.setItem(LOGIN_START_SECRET, 'different-secret')
  zaClient.login = jest.fn(() => true)
  store.addTerminalItem = jest.fn()

  await pubsub.publish(WELCOME_MESSAGE_RENDERED)

  expect(store.addTerminalItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(ErrorMessage))
  const errorMessage = store.addTerminalItem.mock.calls[0][0]
  expect(errorMessage.message).toBe(loginSecurityErrorMsg)
})
```

As I said on my computer it shows correctly that `addTerminalItem` function is called once with the correct argument on both machines I have at home. However this mocked function is never called and fails on 2 of my friends' machines. The actual error message they get is below:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: Any<ErrorMessage>

Number of calls: 0
```

Here are the following things we tried so far:

- Fresh `git clone`, `yarn install`, and `yarn test`. I pass and they don't.
- With `addTerminalItem` mocked, we added a `console.log` inside `addTerminalItem` and it correctly doesn't log, but still 0 number of calls.
- With `addTerminalItem` spyed, we added a `console.log` inside `addTerminalItem` and it correctly logs, but still 0 number of calls (this makes no sense to me)
- We matched our yarn version.
- We carefully debug stepped through the code to make sure all other things were working as expected.

If anyone could give us any pointers here it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "We matched our yarn version." Did you also match the jestjs versions? Appart from that, it is hard to tell. Maybe a difference in the execution time of the async task? A timeout or something? These are just my uneducated guesses.

Comment: I assume you've tried deleting the node_modules folder and running a clean `npm install`?

Comment: I wonder if this is a module caching issue: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#caching-issues

Answer (score 4):

Hard to be definitive without the code at hand, but try using `jest.mock`:

```js
import {addTerminalItem} from "../../../store";

jest.mock('../../../store', () => ({
  addTerminalItem: jest.fn() 
));

//... stuff ...

test('different login start secret in localstorage', async () => {
  localStorage.setItem(LOGIN_START_SECRET, 'different-secret')
  zaClient.login = jest.fn(() => true)
  
  await pubsub.publish(WELCOME_MESSAGE_RENDERED)

  expect(addTerminalItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(ErrorMessage))
  const errorMessage = addTerminalItem.mock.calls[0][0]
  expect(errorMessage.message).toBe(loginSecurityErrorMsg)
})
```